# (La)TeX equivalent of MS Word's "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style"

Tags: spacing, environments

I'm using a `quote` environment to add some references at the beginning of sections with two custom commands.  If I have more than one reference, the `\list` nature of the environment automatically adds margin space around each reference, which is not so pleasant looking. *MS Word* offers the paragraph option "*Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style*" which would be able to suppress the space between these two environments.  **How can I do the same in this situation?**

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Commands for adding references to sections
\newcommand{\referenceurl}[2][See:]{\begin{quote}\emph{#1} \url{#2}\end{quote}}
\newcommand{\reference}[2][See:]{\begin{quote}\emph{#1} #2\end{quote}}

\begin{document}
\section{Important Material}
\referenceurl{http://www.example.com/important_material}
\reference[See also:]{\emph{Important Material for Dummies}, Wikipedians Anonymous Press, 2005.}
\blindtext

\section{Other Material: Ideal Style}
\referenceurl{http://www.example.com/important_material}
\reference[\vskip -6ex\relax See also:]{\emph{Important Material for Dummies}, Wikipedians Anonymous Press, 2005.}
\blindtext

\section{Single Reference: Default style should not change}
\reference{Example page}
\blindtext

\section{Single URL Reference: Default style should not change}
\referenceurl[Excellent Resource:]{http://www.example.com/important_material}
\blindtext

\section{Multiple References: Spacing should be suppressed}
\reference{Textbook}
\reference[Alternate Resource:]{Textbook}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you always have `\reference` after `\referenceur`?

Comment: @egreg No, not always.  And sometimes, there will only be one appearing.

Comment: @egreg In fact, the only reason I have both commands is to automatically format the url in cases where I am simply referencing a url.  You could just consider the case where there are zero/one/two `\reference`s

Comment: Could you supplement your example code with some other typical calls?

Comment: @egreg A few other examples added.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you set up a dedicated list environment for this.  Then the entries are nothing other than `\item`s and do not need special commands.  Such lists are easiest to set-up with  the `enumitem` package.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url,enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlist{references}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[references]{align=left,leftmargin=2em,itemindent=!,rightmargin=2em,labelindent=2em,labelsep=0.3em,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,label=See:,font=\normalfont\textit}

\begin{document}
\section{Important Material}
\begin{references}
  \item \url{http://www.example.com/important_material}
  \item[See also:]{\emph{Important Material for Dummies},
  Wikipedians Anonymous Press, 2005.}
\end{references}
\blindtext

\section{Other Material: Ideal Style}
\begin{references}
  \item \url{http://www.example.com/important_material}
  \item[See also:]{\emph{Important Material for
  Dummies}, Wikipedians Anonymous Press, 2005.}
\end{references}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could detect that and remove teh space automatically, but I wouldn't, I'd use a more explicit markup:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Commands for adding references to sections
\newcommand{\referenceurl}[2][See:]{\par\emph{#1} \url{#2}}
\newcommand{\reference}[2][See:]{\par\emph{#1} #2}
\newenvironment{secrefs}{\quote\parskip0pt\relax}{\endquote}
\begin{document}
\section{Important Material}
\begin{secrefs}
\referenceurl{http://www.example.com/important_material}
\reference[See also:]{\emph{Important Material for Dummies}, Wikipedians Anonymous Press, 2005.}
\end{secrefs}
\blindtext

\section{Other Material: Ideal Style}
\begin{secrefs}
\referenceurl{http://www.example.com/important_material}
\reference[See also:]{\emph{Important Material for Dummies}, Wikipedians Anonymous Press, 2005.}
\end{secrefs}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd define `\newcommand{\referenceurl}[1][See:]{\par\emph{#1} \url}` so that special characters in URLs can be correctly dealt with.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does TeX have any concept similar to the Word option (for a general environment), or is `\parskip` along with margins (like in `\@startsection`) really the closest it gets?

Comment: @cslstr word needs that as its user interface makes it hard to see the difference between one style spanning two paragraphs and two paragraphs separately having the same style, so it needs kludges to fix things up at spurious boundaries. You could do that in TeX either by getting `referenceurl` to look ahead in the token stream for `\reference` and adding corrective space, or getting `\reference` to look in the current vertical list with `\lastskip` and adjusting for space already added. But it isn't really the latex way. More natural to have an environment as here or Andrew's answer.